# How to list all HBase M7 tables from java client

Tags: hbase, mapr

i am able to list HbaseM7 tables using command-

hbase>list '/mapr/cluster/tables/'

But, when I am trying to list the tables using HBaseManager it doesn't workout.. code snippet Configuration conf =//set all m7 cluster; HBaseAdmin admin = new HBaseAdmin(conf); HTableDescriptor[] tables = admin.listTables()

is there any way to pass the table location to listTables() function or may be some property i have to set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is solution for my problem ...[mapr docs](http://doc.mapr.com/display/MapR/Mapping+Table+Namespace+Between+Apache+HBase+Tables+and+MapR+Tables)

But this require configuration update and we don't have that access. some work around i tried-

I ran below shell command from java client using ProcessBuilder and retrieve the list of tables from it.

```
echo "list '/mapr/cluster/tables/'" | hbase shell
```

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't need server side config. You can do the table namespace mapping in client side. See Aditya's answer here [Try to use hbase client communicate with Map M7 native table](http://answers.mapr.com/questions/10144/try-to-use-hbase-client-communicate-with-map-m7-native-table)